# Where is the source code for the GNU C library?

Tags: c, linux

How do I go about finding the source code behind standard C functions (under Linux/Ubuntu 13)?

Case in point, `chdir()`. I know I have to `#include <unistd.h>`  but then I encounter a bug, and I suppose the source code would help me figure out this bug.

Thanks if you point me out to the correct source - but real thanks if you give me a method for finding the correct source file every time I need one.

Comment: The source code for system calls is divided between the [C library](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git) and the kernel. I doubt that it will help you resolve bugs, though, unless you're well-versed in reading OS code.

Comment: I am trying to change dir to a dir with a space in its name. I tried chdir("a b"), chdir("a\ b"), chdir("a\sb"), chdir("'a b'"), chdir("\"a b\""), most of which don't even make sense. Since the bash command works on directories with spaces in their names, it follows that C's chdir must too, and since I can't make it work, I postulated that its source code might help me understand how spaces are managed.

Comment: Did you check what error you're getting?

Comment: no such file or directory, however cd a\ b works perfectly well in bash.

Comment: Are you sure your current working directory is what you think it is?

Comment: [`chdir("a b")`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) should work. Like Paul Griffiths said, you should check the current directory in your program; it's most likely not the one you're using in Bash. Perhaps use e.g. [`getcwd()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html) to get the current directory in your program, and print it?

Comment: Positive. The C "program" in question consists only of this chdir command and a perror() call. The code is in the same directory that contains the 'a b' dir, I compile it in place with gcc chdir.c -o chdirtest, and launch it in place. I already tried printing getcwd(), and it is the correct directory.

Comment: It now works, and I changed it a billion times, so I can't tell what my mistake was. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In many keyboard layouts AltGr+Space maps to non-breaking space, U+00A0 in Unicode. It looks exactly like a normal space, but is a different character. If you occasionally have this occur, then `sed -e 's|\xC2\xA0| |g' -i FILENAME` will convert them back to ordinary spaces.

Comment: Read more about [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall), [Linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) and [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). See also http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project is online at [GNU C Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the source code to the GNU libc is available at https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree